# How to solve this recursive system?

Tags: difference-equations

I try to solve the equation system as

```
p[n_] := Piecewise[{{a, Mod[n, 2] == 0}, {b, Mod[n, 2] == 1}}]

q[n_] := Piecewise[{{c,Mod[n,2]==0},{d,Mod[n,2]==1}}]

RSolve[
{x[n + 1] == (p[n] + y[n])/(p[n] + y[n - 2]), 
y[n + 1] == (q[n] + x[n])/(q[n] + x[n - 2]), x[-2] == A, x[-1] == B,
x[0] == H, y[-2] == J, y[-1] == M, y[0] == L}, {x[n], y[n]}, n
]
```

but I didn't achieve this. When I execute the process, RSolve can't solve the system. How can I deal with this? Thank you.

Comment: Not that it helps with your problem but I'd like to point out that you have used a few reserved keywords as variables in your code (E and D). In order to prevent conflicts you better refrain from using variables with an initial uppercase character.

Comment: You're right. I have edited the expressions. Thank you...

Comment: What, precisely, are you seeking?  This system of difference equations may not have a closed-form analytical solution, just as many differential equations do not.  Nonetheless, they can be solved numerically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to illustrate @bbgodfrey 's comment. If I have coded recursion correctly (noting `NestList` and many other refinements I have not done):

```
p[n_?EvenQ] := a
p[n_] := b
q[n_?EvenQ] := c
q[n_] := d
r[n_, {x__}, {y__}, {pq__}] := 
 Nest[{#[[2]], #[[3]], (p[#[[7]]] + #[[6]])/(p[#[[7]]] + #[[4]]),
     #[[5]], #[[6]],
     (q[#[[7]]] + #[[3]])/(q[#[[7]]] + #[[1]]),
     #[[7]] + 1} /. Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> {pq}] &,
  {x, y, 0}, n]
rc[n_, {x__}, {y__}, {pq__}] := r[n, {x}, {y}, {pq}][[{3, 6}]]
```

You can play:

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Transpose@(rc[#, {x1, x2, x3}, {y1, y2, y3}, {m, s, u, 
        v}] & /@ Range[n]), Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(n\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(n\)]\)"}],
 {n, {10, 20, 30}}, {x1, 1, 10}, {x2, 1, 10}, {x3, 1, 10}, {y1, 1, 
  10}, {y2, 1, 10}, {y3, 1, 10}, {m, 1, 10}, {s, 1, 10}, {u, 1, 
  10}, {v, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Apologies for errors or misunderstanding.

Comment: Inspring from your code I have solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @drxy I am glad it was some help to you in achieving your goal :)